# How do I use custom formatting to change number from ########### to #####.##.##.## in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I have a very large list of numbers that range in size from 9-17 characters. I need to add periods to make them compatible with a specific program.

Example:
1000409180201 --> 10004.09.18.02.01

Is there a way to do this with custom formatting or VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data in **A1** , in another cell enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,5) & "." & MID(A1,6,2) & "." & MID(A1,8,2) & "." & MID(A1,10,2) & "." & RIGHT(A1,2)
```